# How to replace every comma inside round brackets with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string:

```
"a: a(1, 2, 3), b: b(1, 2)"
```

Need to replace every `,` inside round brackets with a `_`. I expect to see:

```
"a: a(1_ 2_ 3), b: b(1_ 2)"
```

Now i use it but only first comma in a brackets is replaced, not all:

```js
let string = "a: a(1, 2, 3), b: b(1, 2)";
string = string.replace(/(\()([\d\.\-\s]+)(\,)([\d\.\-\s]+)(\))/g, '$1$2_$4$5');

// a: a(1_ 2, 3), b: b(1_ 2)
```

Comment: Use `str = str.replace(/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, '$&_')`

Comment: @anubhava yes i just change `'$&_'` to `'_'` because i don't need there commas itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a lookahead based regex:

```
str = str.replace(/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, '$&_')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKQJ3b/1)

```js
var str = "a: a(1, 2, 3), b: b(1, 2)"
str = str.replace(/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, '$&_')
console.log(str)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `,`: match a comma
- `(?=[^()]*\))`: Positive Lookahead to assert that we don't have a closing `)` before matching any `(` or `)` in between
- `$&_`: `$&` is back-reference of the full match and we append a literal `_` at the end

Comment: It add `_` after commas but don't remove commas itself, so i change a bit: `/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, '_'`
Thanx you so much!

Answer (score 2):

We could use a regex replacement with a callback function:

```js
var input = "a: a(1, 2, 3), b: b(1, 2)";
var output = input.replace(/\(\d+(?:, \d+)*\)/g, (match, startIndex, wholeString) => {
    return match.replace(/,/g, "_");
});
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

The idea here is to match each tuple using the following regex pattern:

```
\(\d+(?:, \d+)*\)
```

Then, we pass each match to the callback function which then does a global replacement on `,` to replace with `_`.

Comment: Thank you! So you just use a function in replacement, so simple :)